# Maxtor 40GB HDD shows fatal error while installing windows xp from internal CD-ROM

Tags: windows, hard-drive, compact-disc

Installing windows xp by formatting old windows xp which was crashed....
During Installation it shows following error,

### Fatal Error:

An error occured that prevents setup from continuing.
One of the components that windows need to continue setup could not be installed.
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
Press OK to view setup log file.

### system setup log: C:\windows\setuperr.log

### Error:

sxs.DLL : syntax error in manifest or policy file "E:\I386\asms\io\msft\windows\gdiplus\GDIPLUS.MAN" on line 4.

### Error:

Installation failed: E:\I386\asms. Error message: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.

### Fatal error:

One of the components that windows needs to continue setup could not be installed.
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.

What it means?..
Help me please..
Thank you for reading..

Comment: Make sure that the hard drive that you are installing to and the installation disc/CD drive are all in working order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error likely means the CD you are installing windows from is scratched and it can't read a file during the install process.

You will need to get a new CD or use a [disc repair kit](http://www.amazon.com/b/ref=dp_bc_5?ie=UTF8&node=14084701) to remove the scratch.